# Unity 2D icons in upper-right, click-and-hold

Tags: unity, indicator, 2d

I'm not sure if this is a bug or by design. I just recently installed a clean 11.10 (well, preserving my old home partition from 10.10).

For the icons in the upper right (for me, Dropbox, Sound, Network-Manager, etc), I need to click AND HOLD all these icons in order to keep them open. For example to log out, I click the "power" icon and when I release, the menu goes away. I have to press, hold, and then release on the "log out" item.

If this is a bug, how can I help file? If this is configurable, how do I configure it? I'm not sure what the default experience should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does appear to be a bug, I've seen the same behavior myself intermittently.  I don't see any currently open bugs that appear to be related to this, so I'd suggesting going ahead and filing against unity-2d for the time being and see if someone has suggestions for how to provide more information when the bug is triaged.

Comment: Actually, I was able to find an existing bug for this problem. I noticed it only happens on my second monitor: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/869196

Comment: Interesting, I have actually seen it on my primary (laptop built in) monitor, so I don't think it's directly related to which monitor it's on.  My LP bug searching skills are apparently not great, but I'm glad you found something to track.